# Get info about deleted file if it's only mentioned in mappings

Tags: linux, mmap, memory-mapped-files

If file is deleted but there's at least one fd, it can be accessed by `/proc/$pid/fd/$fd`.
It's possible to get all info as if it's just a regular file. Even some GUI apps can open files from there.

But what can I do if deleted file is only mentioned in memory mappings(`/proc/$pid/maps`)? It's possible to get device, inode and contents of mapped part. But is there a way to get full file size, mtime, ctime and contents of nonmapped parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapped files are accessible though `/proc/$pid/map_files/`. Root permissions are required to read the contents.

Comment: Interesting that the owner and permissions give the impression that the process owner can read the files, even though as you mentioned, it's actually only root who can.